# Как изменить внешний вид рамки окна (рамка JFrame)?

Tags: java, jframe, окно

Рамка вверху, где иконка, имя, и кнопки свернуть, на весь экран и закрыть. Притом нужно оставить функционал. Хотя бы сменить цвет этой рамки. Это возможно? Или нужно полностью убирать ее (setUndecorated) и делать свою?

Answer (score 1):

На сколько мне извесно, нужно создавать свой собственный класс. Это просто.

```
// add pacakge and imports as needed...

/**
 * Sample class implementation for windows with own frame style.
 * Additional constructors may be added as needed. Default constructor used
 * to show principle.
 */
public class MyWindow extends JWindow {
    public MyWindow() {
        super();
        initUI();
    }   

    private void initUI() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new MyWindowFrameTop(this));
        add(new MyWindowFrameLeft(this));
        add(new MyWindowFrameRight(this));
        add(new MyWindowFrameBottom(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Пока не понял. Что за MyWindowFrameTop, Left и т.д.? И допустим я создам этот MyWindow, что мне с ним делать? Все Frame и JFrame наследуются от оригинального Window